# VueJS - How to update component data from a function inside a method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

I'm trying to do a search using Firebase. I have this in my VueJS Code.

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      listings: [],
      searchData: {
        keyword: ""
      }
    }
  },
  name: 'SearchScreen',
  components: {
    ValidationProvider,
    ValidationObserver
  },
  firebase: {
    listings: listingsRef
  },
  methods: {
    search () {
      console.log(this.searchData.keyword)
      listingsRef.orderByChild('location').equalTo(this.searchData.keyword).on('value', function (snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot.val())
        return{
          listings: snapshot.val()
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I do the `console.log` It successfully filters out data and shows the response in the console. But I couldn't update the 'listings' in component data with the response I got from Firebase. Tried `this.listing` but didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: What does `console.log(snapshot.val())` returns? array or object?

Comment: @palash Its an array of objects

Comment: What is `console.log( this )` inside `search ()` at start and inside `.on('value', function (snapshot){ ...` ? Please post the images in your main post.

Comment: @palaѕн I solved it. `(snapshot)=>{}` did the work. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign `this` (component instance) to a global variable `vm` and then in the callback assign that `snapshot.val()` to the `listing` data property as follows :

```
 search () {
      console.log(this.searchData.keyword)
       let vm =this;
      listingsRef.orderByChild('location').equalTo(this.searchData.keyword).on('value', function (snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot.val())

          vm.listings= snapshot.val()

      })
    }
```

or use the callback as an an arrow function `(snapshot)=>{}` :

```
 search () {
      console.log(this.searchData.keyword)
      listingsRef.orderByChild('location').equalTo(this.searchData.keyword).on('value',  (snapshot)=>{
        console.log(snapshot.val())

          this.listings= snapshot.val()

      })
    }
```

Comment: I tried but it says `Cannot set property 'listings' of null`

Comment: of `null` or `undefined` ? did you add `let vm =this;`?

Comment: @SuvinNimnakaSukka This is not possible, as `vm` here refers to the vue instance.

Comment: @Boussadjra `null` . Yes I added that too

Comment: @palaѕн  what do you mean?

Comment: did you try out the second solution using arrow function?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to bind `this` to your function:

```
listingsRef.orderByChild('location').equalTo(this.searchData.keyword).on('value', function (snapshot){
    this.listings = snapshot.val()
}.bind(this))
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Didnt work :( But @Boussadjra gave a solution with an arrow function and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Ok! Nice to know! :) Don't forget to upvote @Boussadjra 's answer and accept it as the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

to the search function add a reference to the component

```
thisComponent = this
```

then inside the function (snapshot)

```
use thisComponent.searchData.keyword = (whatever)
```