# VueJs UI not updated after data is fetched from PouchDB

Tags: vue.js, pouchdb

This is my code

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        pageTitle: 'All Notes',
        notes: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
        db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(function(result){
            this.notes = result.rows;
            console.log(this.notes);
        }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
        
    
  }
})
```

*console.log(this.notes)* logs the fetched data in console. But the UI is not updated. The frontend code is below

```
<div class="note" v-for="note in notes">
                <p class="category"><span>{{note.category}}</span> <small class="ts"> {{note.date}} </small> </p>
                <p class="content"> {{note.content}} </p>
                

            </div>
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/61324085/8172857

Comment: When you use `this` inside the promise function you are not referring to the Vue instance but to the callback function's context it self. You must first assign the Vue instance's context to a variable and then refer to that variable from within the callback. Ex: `const that = this; `then inside the callback use `that.notes`

Comment: @Chin.Udara  That did work. Thank you.